# Why I am getting error on comparing two dates

Tags: swift, date, calendar

I am trying to compare two dates, One is from server and other is my local device time.

**This is code snippet.**

```
let deviceDate = Date()

let calendar = Calendar.current
let dateNewServer = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 120, to: dateFromServer!)

//deviceDate -> 2019-06-25 08:28:03 +0000
//dateFromServer -> 2019-06-21 20:00:00 +0000
//dateNewServer -> 2019-06-21 22:00:00 +0000

if (deviceDate >= dateFromServer) && (deviceDate <= dateNewServer){
    print("Live Matches")
}else{
    print("Old/Upcoming Matches")
}
```

**Error:**

Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Date' and 'Date?'

Comment: What is the value of `dateFromServer`?

Comment: Its a date of type UTC, I am getting from server (2019-06-21 20:00:00 +0000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dateNewServer` is an `optional`. So you need to unwrap it first before using further. This is the what your error says.

> func date(byAdding component: Calendar.Component, value: Int, to date:
>   Date, wrappingComponents: Bool = default) -> Date?

**Solution:** Unwrap it using *optional binding*`(if let)` or *forced unwrapping*`(!)`. *Optional binding* is more safer way to unwrap an `optional`.

```
if let dateNewServer = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 120, to: dateFromServer) {
    if deviceDate.compare(dateFromServer) == .orderedDescending && deviceDate.compare(dateNewServer) == .orderedAscending {
        print("Live Matches")
    } else {
        print("Old/Upcoming Matches")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are trying to compare Optional(Date) and Date types. Try unwrapping your `dateFromServer` variable.
E.g.

```
if (deviceDate >= dateFromServer!){
    print("Live Matches")
}else{
    print("Old/Upcoming Matches")
}
```

Also, you are comparing `Date` and `String` here `deviceDate <= "\(dateNewServer)"`

Answer (score 0):

```
   let checkGreaterDate = deviceDate.isGreaterThanDate(dateToCompare: dateFromServer!)
    let checkLesserDate = deviceDate.isLessThanDate(dateToCompare: dateNewServer!)
    if  checkGreaterDate && checkLesserDate{
        print("Live Matches")
    }else{
        print("Old/Upcoming Matches")
    }
```

Helper Methods

```
    func isLessThanDate(dateToCompare: Date) -> Bool {
    //Declare Variables
    var isLess = false

    //Compare Values
    if self.compare(dateToCompare as Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending {
        isLess = true
    }

    //Return Result
    return isLess
}


func isGreaterThanDate(dateToCompare: Date) -> Bool {
    //Declare Variables
    var isGreater = false

    //Compare Values
    if self.compare(dateToCompare as Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending {
        isGreater = true
    }

    //Return Result
    return isGreater
}
```